# How can I specify confidence in training data?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, knn, training-data, naivebayes

I am classifying data with categorical variables. It is data where people have provided information.

My training dataset is of varying quality. I have a greater confidence in some of the data i.e. I have a higher confidence that people have provided correct information whereas in some the data I am not so sure.

How can I pass this information into a classification algorithm such as Naive Bayes or K nearest neighbour?
Or should I instead look to another algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do, is to provide individual weights (for the importance/confidence) for each data point you have.

For instance, if you are very certain that one data point is of higher quality and should have a higher weight than others, in which you are less confident in, you can specify that when fitting your classifier.

Sklearn provides for instance the Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier ([GaussianNB](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB)) for that.
Here, you can specify `sample_weights` when calling the [`fit()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.fit) method.